# Issues with SSISDB - SQL migration 2012 > 2016

Tags: sql-server, migration

I have a puzzle. We've been migrating a clustered instance from SQL 2012 to SQL 2016.
I didn't realize in advance that SSISDB requires additional steps and due to OS issues I cannot get access to the old instance as of now - we're working on it.
What I've done after we've realized that SSISDB needs different approach:

- SSISDB master key was regenerated with 'force' option and it an encyption by SMK was added
- Backup of new master key was taken afterwards
- A new backup of SSISDB was taken
- Login  ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobLogin## was created based on the script from a third server and disabled
- User  ##MS_SSISServerCleanupJobUser## was mapped to that login
- Procedure  [dbo].[sp_ssis_startup] was created in master based on the script from a third server
- Job 'SSIS Server Maintenance Job' was created based on the script from a third server
  Still I have following issues:
- 'Database Upgrade' option is greyed out under Integration Service Catalog
- I cannot open properties of SSISDB under Integration Service Catalog because of following error: Invalid object name 'SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)
- I cannot export the only Project from Catalog because of: An error occurred during decryption. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15466)

I've tried to delete the SSIDB, create a new catalogue and then restore SSISDB with overwrite again, but it didn't help. Since I'm not the biggest expert on SSISDB, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Small follow-up: SQL2016 introduced changes in DB design (new tables), so any pre-SQL2016 SSISDB restored on SQL2016+ will have an old design and SSIS/SQL2016 won't be able to use it anyway.
If that's is indeed the case here, we will try to do the migration either via Visual Studio to a blank SSISDB or via a third machine with SQL2012 and perform an inplace upgrade to SQL2016 there.